# A word or phrase for turning something into nothing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a character delivering a monologue (fortunately not too long), and want to capture the idea that something turns into nothing, using a single word or striking turn of phrase.

"Evaporate" is the closest I got, but it doesn't go far enough and carries with it a reversibility.

"Pass out of existence" and "turn to nothing" are bland but accurate. "Turn to dust" also leaves a residue, and invokes Tyrion's famous threat.

So, I've run dry.

Paradoxically, there are many great ways of saying that nothing turns into something. Of course there are...

**Edit**
I don't believe the exact sentence will be helpful in this instance, but here's some context to back it up.

The character is talking about how the achievement of his goal will make all the crimes committed in it's service irrelevant. But it's not so much irrelevance, instead the notion that they will never have happened at all.

The sentence:
"When we achieve our goal, all this will [insert phrase here].

Another candidate is, "be undone". That's okay, but implies the crimes and their effects being rectified, not simply ceasing to have happened.

**Edit 2**
A note about the audience: The book is in the action/adventure genre and targeted at adult male readers.

The character is a well-educated male in his thirties, and so is the character bring addressed.

Comment: Can you add the exact phrase your character will say? Context is relevant.

Comment: Yes, it helps to know WHAT turns into nothing. Please include your sentence.

Comment: It's also relevant to tell us about the audience.  If it's important then perhaps worth spending a few more words on so your audience have time to assimilate the issue.

Comment: @user66974 I've made the edit you requested, but I don't the sentence in all iets simplicity wil be helpful. I therefore added a bit more context.

Comment: @fev In this case he's referring to actions taken and damage caused. I'm betting the answer will be metaphoric though, in the way "evaporating" doesn't need to be used only with fluids.

Comment: @PeterFox That's a great point. I've edited the question.

Comment: Unless this is a sci-fi creation, you cannot _unhappen_ things. What you might be needing is saying that those crimes lose any negative character. I would personally something like: _**When we achieve our goal, all this will make sense/be justified**_.

Comment: @fev You're changing the meaning even further away from the options I listed in the question. You can't create something from nothing either, and yet there are many ways of saying that. I'm just looking for the opposite.

Comment: "they will never have happened at all." As in time-travel? Or do you mean they won't be crimes because, having won, they will absolve themselves of their own sins?

Comment: Is there a reason you're rejecting disappear, vanish, and synonyms? They seem obvious. I still don't think you've quite pinned down what sort of disappearance/abnegation/undoing you mean, so looking at a thesaurus and saying why none of those words are right would help.

Comment: A common way to say is _like it never happened_. "When we achieve our goal, all this will be like it never happened". I'm not sure if it is acceptable enough for your criteria and context. _Unexist_ is a verb given by [_Wiktionary_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unexist) and can be used both transitively and intransitively, but it is a very rare word; could possibly work in a literary context. _Unhappen_ is a rare word option also but only used intransitively.

Comment: If a phrase would be acceptable how about: "the criminality in my crimes will just vanish (evaporate)". He still has done what he did, but it is not considered a crime any more.

Comment: The title question asks for an action imposed ('A great word or phrase for turning something into nothing') such as 'obliviate', whereas the body is asking for the consequence ('be obliviated/erased'). Will either type of answer be suitable?

Comment: All this will be **vaporized**.

Answer (score 1):

**expunged**

Crimes that "disappear" are *expunged.*

Meaning *sealed or destroyed, making the records nonexistent or unavailable to the general public* (Wikipedia).

> To “expunge” is to “erase or remove completely.” In law, “expungement”
> is the process by which a record of criminal conviction is destroyed
> or sealed from state or federal record. An expungement order directs
> the court to treat the criminal conviction as if it had never
> occurred, essentially removing it from a defendant’s criminal record
> as well as, ideally, the public record.
> [[ABA]](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/public_education/publications/teaching-legal-docs/what-is-_expungement-/)

Quoted definition from OL&G, presumably, or they are the same in any case.

Answer (score 1):

**annihilate** : to cause to cease to exist : to do away with entirely so that nothing remains (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annihilate).

From Middle French annihilation, from Latin ad (“to”) + nihil (“nothing”) (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annihilation).

Answer (score 0):

"When we achieve our goal, all this will **cease to exist**.”

Answer (score 0):

"I have a character delivering a monologue (fortunately not too long), and want to capture the idea that **something turns into nothing**, using a single word or striking turn of phrase."

> When we achieve our goal, all this will lift like the fog.

Answer (score 0):

**[Evanish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evanish)**

> 1 : VANISH, DISAPPEAR
>
> 2 : to cease to be

The word was [more popular in the past](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evanish%2C%20platypus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), which may lend to a (somewhat false) feeling of "well-educated", maybe if it's uttered by the character, and especially if the "well-educated" implies the character tends toward being a pendant.